5 Pin Relay Wiring - Is this possible?
I have an Engel Fridge/Freezer in the rear of my 4WD. When driving and during short camping setups I will run it off the car battery (no issues there). However, when we go away with our caravan (travel trailer in the USA) and set up off grid for more than one night I will run an umbilical from the caravan to the car to run the fridge freezer as we have 1440 W of solar and 600 Ah of battery in the van so more than enough to run this ancillary fridge. It pulls 3 A full time as we run it as a freezer on these occasions.
Will wiring a relay as depicted be electrically sound?
Whilst there are manual switch options I could explore I came up with this idea using a 5 pin relay to eliminate the potential for human errors (with manual switch options) but need some professional and qualified experienced input on the idea.
The background to the circuit diagram is that I would like to automate the switching from car battery power to the van battery power without any human having to change a power input selector switch because certain humans may not think about doing the manual switch over thingy and as a result a ton of meat will end up defrosting and potentially going bad or requiring rapid consumption.
The fridge remains plugged into car power all the time via the relay.  However, I just want my fellow campers (lets just leave the description thus) to be able to just plug in the Anderson umbilical from the van into the car and not require them to do anything else to keep it nice and simple.
How I believe it will work:
Power from the car battery will power the fridge using the pin 30/87a relationship but in reverse. So pin 30 will be the output and pin 87a (NC) will be the input. As it is normally closed the fridge will run from the car battery only. I believe the earths will run to the car battery as well - given it is the source of the potential energy difference.
Once I plug the van in (via an Anderson plug) both pins 86 and 87 will receive power from the van. The Pin 86/85 pair will turn the relay on (as this is their usual operating direction) which will send power to pin 30 from pin 87 and then on to run the fridge.
I have shown a resistor at the input to pin 86 but it may not be necessary I suspect?
As the positive from the car battery has now been excluded from the circuit, I believe the earths will now flow correctly back via the Anderson to the van battery.
Will this idea SAFELY work and is it electrically sound please?


Yes, it looks like it should work and no, you shouldn't use a resistor. But a car or caravan forum is probably a better place to ask.

Thanks for the reply Finbarr.  Appreciate it mate!
